# Добавление записи в таблицу с условием

Tags: sql

Помогите с запросом в процедуре.
Суть в том, что есть процедура, которая добавляет товар. И по id и нужно проверить, есть ли такой же товар с таким же id, если нет, то добавляем в таблицу.

```
 create PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddProduct]
            @id int,
            @name nvarchar(50)
```

Я тип пытался написать в таком ключе

```
If select count(*) from ProductTable where ProductTable.Id = @id >0 
// то добавляем.
```

Но что-то не то

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте такой вариант:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddProduct]
    @id int,
    @name nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
 IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ProductTable WHERE id=@id)
  PRINT 'Товар уже существует'
 ELSE
  BEGIN
   INSERT INTO ProductTable
   VALUES (@id, @name)
   PRINT 'Товар добавлен'
  END
END
```